# Transact-SQL Trigger with loop

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have question that I am stuck with for a couple of hours. I have 3 Tables and I want a trigger on table Project that checks if someone update Leiternr to null it can only be done when the Pronr of Projekt table has no Mitnr from Table MiPro

[image]

What I have so far is this. But it doesn't work any more when more than 1 Leitnr is null. Which is kinda logically cause of "where pro
nr = (select pronr from projekt3 where leiternr is null)) > 0"

But how can I achieve what I want?

```
create trigger Leiternr on projekt3 after update
as 
begin
if (select count(*) from mipro3 where pronr = (select pronr from projekt3 where leiternr is null)) > 0
begin
    RAISERROR ('Projekt has still Member', 16, 1);
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    RETURN 
end
```

end

Comment: First, no one but you knows what "doesn't work" means. Be specific. Next, you included an IMAGE of 3 tables - yet one appears totally pointless. Is it? Finally, don't post important information as images. For issues like this, one needs to see DDL for the tables involved to understand the relationships among the tables. Do that as a script - which includes sample data in the form of insert statements. It appears you need to test for existence - there is no need to count anything as far as I can tell. But your description is not clear.

Comment: sorry for the mess. yeah one of the table is pointless. I just added this table for  of completion. I thought a picture is better than the DDL. But yeah i could have been add the ralations :/ Thanks for your hints. cheers

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're really close. I think you just need to change your "=" to an "in". That way you can compare to multiple records.  Like this:

```
create trigger Leiternr on projekt3 after update
as 
begin
if (select count(*) from mipro3 where pronr in (select pronr from projekt3 where leiternr is null)) > 0
begin
    RAISERROR ('Projekt has still Member', 16, 1);
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    RETURN 
end
```

Comment: Just to clarify, this is designed to check if there are *any* rows in mipro3 where the corresponding projekt3 has the null value. There is no check here to see if the specific projekt3 row being updated is null, its *any* row. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what i needed. <3 Works like a charm :) Im Happy.

Comment: Great! I'm glad that worked for you! Would you mind marking my solution as the answer, too? At this point, I'm new enough I need all the points I can get :-p